# How do I list entries from a single author?

Tags: entries, users, author

I'm returning the username as the second segment `/blog/username` and then setting the `username` var to `craft.request.segment(2)`.

I'm looking to list a group of entries by that author (username). I've tried:

```
{% set blogPosts = craft.entries.section('blog').relatedTo(username) %}
```

I've also tried this:

```
{% set blogPosts = craft.entries.section('blog').relatedTo({ targetElement: username, field: 'author' })%}
```

Anyone have a way to list through entries related by author?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
{# First, grab the username from the URI #}
{% set username = craft.request.segment(2) %}

{# Then, grab the user based on the username %}
{% set user = craft.users.username(username).first() %}

{# Make sure we actually found a user #}
{% if user %}
    {% set blogPosts = craft.entries.section('blog').authorId(user.id).find() %}

    Found: {{ blogPosts|length }} blog posts.
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Brad. The first part is working with a bit of modification `{% set user = craft.users.username(craft.request.segment(2)).first() %}`; `{{ user }}` returns the correct value, however when added to `.relatedTo()` it doesn't return any results (should in this case have 2 entries returned).

Comment: Try your 2nd example, then, with a slight modification to field {% set blogPosts = craft.entries.section('blog').relatedTo({ targetElement: user, field: 'authorId' })%}

Comment: That didn't work either. I tried a few different iterations of the same line: `{ targetElement: user, field: authorId }` `{ targetElement: user.id, field: authorId }` `{ targetElement: userd, field: 'authorId' }` `{ targetElement: user.id, field: 'authorId' }` You get the idea.

Comment: Check the latest edit.  Actually tested this one. :)

Comment: Now we're in business! Thanks for that. I guess I'll have to install the Happy Brad plugin now... -sigh-

Comment: Only happy when I'm drunk and my current status is sadly, very sober.

Comment: @BradBell is there a way to get around authors not showing up because they are not yet `verified`?