# Find entries related to user and display field name

Tags: relations, field

If I’m finding all the entries that are related to a user, how could I get the field handle that the found user is referenced from?

```
{% set events = craft.entries.section('events').relatedTo(user) %}
{% for event in events %}

  {# What goes here? Hypothetical code based on non-existent method would be: #}

  {% set field = craft.fields.relatedTo(user) %}
  {{ field.title }}

{# Obviously this isn't possible. Any way to accomplish something like this? #}

{% endfor %}
```

There are multiple users fields in the found entries, and there will be different logic depending on which field the user is found.

Comment: Possible duplicate http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/720/101

Comment: @MarkBusnelliJr Not quite, the main question here isn't how to find the related entries, but how to find & display the field handle that the relation is referenced.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What could work for you is to get the events for each field separatly:

```
{% set firstEvents = craft.entries.section('events').relatedTo({
    element: user,
    field: 'firstEntriesField'
}) %}

{% set secondEvents = craft.entries.section('events').relatedTo({
    element: user,
    field: 'secondEntriesField'
}) %}
```

If you need them combined in one loop, I can't think of another way other than to query x + 1 times:

```
{% set allEvents = craft.entries.section('events').relatedTo({
    element: user,
}) %}

{% set firstEventsIds = craft.entries.section('events').relatedTo({
    element: user,
    field: 'firstEntriesField'
}).ids() %}

{% set secondEventsIds = craft.entries.section('events').relatedTo({
    element: user,
    field: 'secondEntriesField'
}).ids() %}

{% for event in allEvents %}
    {% if event.id in firstEventsIds %}
        {# Event related through firstEntriesField #}
    {% elseif event.id in secondEventsIds %}
        {# Event related through secondEntriesField #}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```